# csv_expert of Postgres hook in Airflow does not write anything to table without errors

Tags: postgresql, airflow, psycopg2

I want to write a CSV file to a table in Postgres via Airflow.
I came across this Airflow [documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/4c1fcee6ba1559fcb53836ac7fcccd68b1891d93/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py#L116) denoting that the hook already has a builtin function for CSV export.
And used this [thread](https://learningtotest.com/2019/09/13/using-postgreshook-copy_expert-method/) on how to use it.
I have a python operator whose python_callable is as follows:

```
def copy_expert_csv():
    hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='warehouse',host='data-warehouse',
                        database='datalake',
                        user='root',
                        password='root',
                        port=9999)
    with hook.get_conn() as connection:
            hook.copy_expert("""COPY datalake.public.wcc_users  FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER
                        DELIMITER as ',' """,
                        'includes/cleaned_data/wwc/' + str(date.today()) + '_wwc_cleaned ')
            connection.commit()
```

The task finishes successfully as shown in the image.
[image]
:

And there is no error logs on my database either:

```
materials-data-warehouse-1  | 2022-04-29 17:43:01.942 UTC [198] STATEMENT:  COPY datalake.public.wcc_users  FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV) HEADER
```

My file has around 1000 rows. However, when I select from my table, there are 0 rows inserted.

The column naming in table are different from the file and also 2 columns have date and timestamp datatypes rather than text. Can it be the cause? Then why no errors are thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that table definition was incorrect. This throws no errors but inserts nothing either.